# How would I return a salary + a 5% raise?

Tags: sql

I am trying to return a salary + a 5% raise. I thought the following code would work but it gives me an error. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT last_name || ' ' || salary || ' ' ||salary*.05+salary || ' '  FROM f_staffs;
```

Comment: Maybe... cast((salary  * 1.05 ) as varchar(30))

Comment: What database are you using and what is the error?

Comment: Since he's concatenating with ||, looks like Oracle to me

Comment: ... providing more details improve the changes to have a better feedback. e.g. what is the database you are running, what is the error message, etc.

Comment: sorry its Oracle and A.H.. already answered it for me

Comment: @husbas: I love questions like yours. If they told you they were using the payroll database, how would that help? Hint: I think you rather meant DBMS or perhaps SQL product.

Comment: @onedaywhen I meant the database product such as MySQL, Oracle or MS SQL. The syntax of concatenation differs for different databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is this:

```
SELECT last_name || ' ' || salary || ' ' || (1.05*salary) || ' ' FROM f_staffs;
```

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

are you need all in one field? if yes assuming oracle:

```
SELECT last_name || ' ' || to_char(salary) || ' ' ||to_char(salary*.05+salary) || ' ' FROM f_staffs;
```